# Fluid margin wider than its initial pixel value

Tags: css

It's probably some sort of naive detail forgotten, but anyway.

I got an `h2`with a paragraph right below it. The paragraph currently holds a `margin-top` of `30px` separating it from the `h2` and I want to make it flexible by applying a percentage. I'm targeting 1440px as 100% and my paragraph is a child of a `div` whose `width` is simply 100% (not declared) and the `div`, in turn, is inside other two block-level elements before the body itself is reached. All of them have their widths of 100%. The problem arises when I set the `margin` as `2.083...%` to replace the original `30px` as the space becomes much wider. Knowing that the margin calculates its value from its container's width and that is 100%, I'm wondering why it's wider.

```css
#about {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.about_center {
padding-top: 13.9%; /*200px*/
position: relative;
background-color: rgba(239,197,198,1.00); 
}

#about .about_center h2 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
word-spacing: 5px;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 3.8em;
line-height: 120%;
text-align: center; 
background-color: rgba(221,165,228,1.00);
}

#first-paragraph {
color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.8);
margin: 2.083333333333333% /*30px*/ auto 200px;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
background-color: rgb(172,235,191);
line-height: 120%;
}

#timeline p {
font-family: "Lato";
font-size: 2em;
text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  
  <div class="about_center">
    
    <h2>Example here...</h2>
    
    <div id="timeline">
      <p id="first-paragraph">Alright, dude...</p>
      
      <div id="aaaaa">
        <h3>Music</h3>
        <p>ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample</p>
      </div>

      <div id="bbbbb">

        <h3>Web</h3>
        <p>ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample</p>
      </div>    
             
      <div id="ccccc">
        <h3>Local</h3>                        
        <p>ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: *"I got an h2with a paragraph right below it.."* - There is no `h2` just before the `p#first-paragraph` on which you are specifying the margin.

Comment: Did you mean `h3 + p { margin-top: 2.083%; }` ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought "visually". The paragraph is right after a div #timeline and the h2 before the div.